# How do I disable popup block in undetected_chromedriver.v2

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, popupwindow

**Other people's solution isn't working, so I need help.**

I can't use normal Chrome driver since it can't login to Google.

Python selenium.

I tried

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
```

And

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.popups": 1,
})
```

None of above worked.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution worked for me while using undetected_chromedriver.v2,
with the following package versions:

- undetected_chromedriver==3.0.6

Python Selenium version:

- selenium==3.141.0

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc

options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")        
self.driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
```

The undetected chrome driver initialised with this would have the popup blocks as disabled by default.
I hope this helps! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Options class to create an instance of the Chrome options, and then use the add_experimental_option method to add the "safebrowsing" option with the value {"enabled": False} so can you try this code;

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("safebrowsing", {"enabled": False})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: its still blocked, not working. I'm using undetected_chromedriver.v2 actually